# Rails 3.2 - undefined method `where' for #<Array:... - Query of Model.where()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql

I am trying to compare fields from a given `Header` to other fields in the `Alarm` model. As you can see in the code I filter the alarms in 3 different steps. The first 2 work perfectly. However, the last one does not work.
It said:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:...
```

As far as I understand `.where` is a class method that works with array. Why does not work here?
I also tried with `.find_all_by` and different things... but to not avail.

```
@header = Header.find(1)

# Extracts those alarms that are ACTIVE and have something in common with the tittles
@alarmsT = Alarm.activated.where("keyword in (?)", [@header.title_es, @header.title_en, @header.title_en])

# Extracts alarms when Header has at least the same categories as an alarm
@alarmsT = @alarmsT.select do |alarm| 
   @header.category_ids.all?{|c| alarm.category_ids.include? c }
end

// this is the one that does NOT work
# Extract alarms which share the same location as Header.events' town
@alarmsF = [] 
@header.events.each do |e|
    @alarmsF =  @alarmsF + @alarmsT.where("alarms.location LIKE ?", e.town)
end
```

Any help spotting what I am missing much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first line, you're successfully returning an `ActiveRecordRelation` object in `@alarmsT`

```
# Extracts those alarms that are ACTIVE and have something in common with the tittles
@alarmsT = Alarm.activated.where("keyword in (?)", [@header.title_es, @header.title_en, @header.title_en])
```

At this point you could apply additional `.where(...)` methods, conditions or scopes on `@alarmsT` to further build up the ARel expression and the results returned.

However, you then run a filter over this relation, converting `@alarmsT` to an instance of `Array`

```
# Extracts alarms when Header has at least the same categories as an alarm
@alarmsT = @alarmsT.select do |alarm| 
   @header.category_ids.all?{|c| alarm.category_ids.include? c }
end
```

You can no longer build up the ARel expression, since `Array` doesn't know about your ARel's `.where(...)` method, or any of your `Alarm` model's scopes or attributes. This is why in the code below you're getting the `undefined method 'where' for #<Array:...` error -- you're calling `.where()` on an instance of `Array`; a method that does not exist.

```
@alarmsF = [] 
@header.events.each do |e|
  @alarmsF =  @alarmsF + @alarmsT.where("alarms.location LIKE ?", e.town)
end
```

You can fix this by not doing the select to filter by category ids and instead using a join. Building such a join (to verify existence of at least a subset of values in a related table/column) is documented quite a bit on places easily found through google and here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation. Helped to improve my understanding. I will have a look to see if I can build that join. So far, I got no idea how to approach it.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Deefour said, with `select` you are collecting data in a `Array` instead of a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Are you sure you need the `LIKE` query? by looking at it i guess you could go with a simple straight-forward comparison. If my assumption is true, you could rearange the last part of your code:

```
@alarmsF = []
towns_from_events = @header.events.collect(&:town)

@alarmsT.each do |alarmsT|
    @alarmsF << alarmsT if towns_from_events.include?(alarmsT.location)
end
```

Comment: Your assumption is absolutely right. And this piece of code works beautifully! Thanks